# SyntaxError: Unexpected token else (codecademy.com)

Tags: javascript

I am having a few issues being a new programmer to JS.

It is giving me an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token else

Any help would be well appreciated!

Here is the code:

```
// Write your function below. 
// Don't forget to call your function!
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
    if (numHours >= 8) console.log("You are getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!");
} else {
    return "Get some more shut eye";
};
sleepcheck(10);
sleepcheck(5);
sleepcheck(8);
```

Comment: There’s a `{` missing after `if (…)` and another `}` missing after your function definition.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `{`

```
// Write your function below. 
// Don't forget to call your function!
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
if (numHours >= 8) { console.log("You are getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!");
} else {
    return "Get some more shut eye";
};
sleepcheck(10);
sleepcheck(5);
sleepcheck(8);
```

Comment: Thanks! Going to accept answer when 1 minute limit ends. :)

Answer (score 0):

There’s a `{` missing after `if (…)` and another `}` missing after your function definition:

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
    if (numHours >= 8) {
        console.log("You are getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!");
    }
    else {
        return "Get some more shut eye";
    }
};
sleepcheck(10);
sleepcheck(5);
sleepcheck(8);
```

Also, a little bit of code review:

Keep your `return`s and `console.log`s consistent. In one case you return a string, in the other case you log something. Do the same thing for *both* cases.